# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on line 13 Error: SELECT * FROM req WHERE id='4'

Tags: php, insert

I seem to get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hr/accept.php on line 13
>   Error: SELECT * FROM req WHERE id='4'

With this code :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if (isset($_POST['row-id'])) {

    $rowToadd = intval($_POST['row-id']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM req WHERE id='$rowToadd'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_req,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $query = "INSERT INTO a_req (user, desc, price, cat) VALUES ('" . $row['user'] ."', '" . $row['desc'] . "', '" . $row['budget'] ."', '" . $row['cat'] ."')"; // Or whatever your primary key is for the row, in my case "id". LIMIT 1 kind of gives added assurance that it won't delete tons of stuff if you make a mistake.

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: So `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` failed, do error checking on it. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php Your second query also is open to SQL injections. The `LIMIT 1 ` gives no such assurance (also there's no delete here so not sure what this comment is in reference to).

Answer (score 3):

On line 13 you are using the wrong variable; `$result`, not `$result_req`.

Comment: I'd post that as a statement, not question.

Comment: This then lead the error into :  `Error: SELECT * FROM req WHERE id=4`

Comment: @TristanSchlarman is it possible that you have wrong table and/or id ? and did you select which database to connect in your `mysqli_connect();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is triggered because `$result_req` is an undeclared variable. Use `$result` instead in the line:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_req,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You should also improve your error correction by checking whether the first query failed before you try to `fetch_array` and execute the 2nd query.

```
if (isset($_POST['row-id'])) {

    $rowToadd = (int) $_POST['row-id'];
    $error = null;

    $sql = "...";
    $result = mysqli_query(...) or $error = $conn->error;

    //on error, exit early
    if($error){
        echo "Error: $sql <br/> $error"; exit;        
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $query = "...";

    $conn->query($sql) or $error = $conn->error;

    if($error){
        echo "Error: $sql <br/> $error"; exit;
    }else{
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
}
```